# RxJs 6: Get ConnectableObservable from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Angular 6 requires an update to RxJs 6 and with that RxJs update the `Observable.publish()` function is gone. I found a `publish` operator in `RxJs/operators` but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it.

How could this RxJs 5 code be rewritten to work with RxJs 6?

`const myConnectableObservable = this.getObservable().publish()`

Comment: As a temporarily work-around you can use the rxjs-compat module to keep compatibility with version 5.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler for sure, and thanks. I was trying to be proactive about fixing it now at my leisure instead of being forced to with RxJs 7. Though at that point there should be more resources online.

Comment: Yeah, I'm facing some issues with the migration, too, and trying to don't use the rxjs-compat in order to have less problems when version 7 will be released.

Comment: `this.getObservable().pipe(publish()) as ConnectableObservable<any>` but, ideally, with an appropriate type instead of the `any`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50166414/6680611

Comment: See this issue - (and especially my comment) - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2972

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import { ConnectableObservable } from "rxjs"
import { publish } from "rxjs/operators";

const myConnectableObservable: ConnectableObservable<MyClass> = myService.getObservable().pipe(publish()) as ConnectableObservable<MyClass>;
```

Special thanks to @cartant

Comment: It seems `Observable` has a `publish` method. I tried to use it directly but got error that `publish` doesn't exist. I had to use `pipe(publish())`. Could you please tell me why directly using `publish` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively try this version without casting to the `ConnectableObservable` type. This way you don't need import and cast.
**This is needed because according to the documentation `pipe()` always returns Observable.**

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, publish } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = interval(400);

const observable = publish()(source.pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
));

observable.connect();
```

Originally posted on RxJS GitHub repository as an issue, see [link to the issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3595).